# Evaluating series sum with floor

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a closed form expression or a good approximation for the following expression:
\begin{equation}
\sum^{\infty}_{k=n+1} {\left\lfloor \frac{k}{n+1} \right\rfloor p^k}
\end{equation}

Knowing that $n\geq1$ and $0< p< 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing $k=(n+1)q+r$,
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac k{n+1}\right\rfloor p^k=\sum_{q=1}^\infty\sum_{r=0}^nqp^{(n+1)q+r}= \sum_{q=1}^\infty qp^{(n+1)q}\cdot \sum_{r=0}^np^r.$$
Now
$$\sum_{r=0}^np^r=\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p}$$
and 
$$ \sum_{q=1}^\infty qx^q=\frac x{(1-x)^2},$$
so 
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac k{n+1}\right\rfloor p^k=\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p}\cdot\frac{p^{n+1}}{(1-p^{n+1})^2}=\frac{p^{n+1}}{(1-p)(1-p^{n+1})}. $$

Comment: Great! In the beginning, I ruled out the possibility of the existence of a closed form.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last equality? I don't get how from $\sum_{q=1}^\infty qx^q=\frac x{(1-x)^2},$ you deduce $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac k{n+1}\right\rfloor p^k=\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{1-p}\cdot\frac{p^{n+1}}{(1-p^{n+1})^2}$. SInce it's not in the same form